# Change table direcion to vertical mode in mobil

Tags: css, mobile, grid, rows, direction

I have a table and it is normally display data in horizontal mode. I want to change cell direction order to bottom in mobil mode like grid system.

I written this code under css style:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  img {
    height: 450px;
    width: 450px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

 tr, td, th {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 480px;
  }
```

The direction is ok with this code, but table has deformation too, padding and width not change anything. I tried other display sections like grid, table, table-row but i could not made this.

Please help to how can i correct it.

HTML

```
<table class="kadir">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://www.bizimduvar.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/bizimduvar.png" alt="" /></td><td>cell2_1</td><td>cell3_1</td><td>cell4_1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://www.bizimduvar.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/bizimduvar.png" alt="" /></td><td>cell2_2</td><td>cell3_2</td><td>cell4_2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://www.bizimduvar.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/bizimduvar.png" alt="" /></td><td>cell2_3</td><td>cell3_3</td><td>cell4_3</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://www.bizimduvar.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/bizimduvar.png" alt="" /></td><td>cell2_3</td><td>cell3_3</td><td>cell4_3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: Hi, i added html code, please can you look?

Comment: Probably the problem you find is due only to the fact that you are specifying the width in an absolute way (in px), try not to specify the width or specify it with % or vw

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 td {
    display: table-row;
  }
}
```

transforming the `TD`s from cells contained in rows to rows themselves, but with `table-row` you can't specify margins.

With `display: block` you can

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  td {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is better, thank you. But why cell padding return to zero? I am adding to mobil css to tr, td, th new padding value but not applying.

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer